# for loop not iterating through all list elements in python

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop

```
things="pen pencil apple mango litchi grapes pear song music"
stuff=things.split(" ")
items=["a","b","c","d"]

for word in items:
    next_one=items.pop()
    stuff.append(next_one)
print(stuff)
```

when I run this code, the resulting list shows that only last two elements are appended from items. Why is it not appending all the elements?

Comment: `stuff.append(word)`  remove `next_one=items.pop()
`

Answer (score 0):

Therefore that you modify items reference You will only add two elements.
Below you can see all values in items variable in every step of loop.

STEP 1

items = ["a","b","c","d"]
next_one = 'd'

STEP 2

items = ["a","b","c"]
next_one = 'c'

STEP 3

items = ["a","b"]
**So here the loop ends**

To solve it you can change

```
for word in items:
```

to

```
while(items):
```

Or you can write it in one line:

```
stuff.extend(list(reversed(items)))
```

Comment: Why does the loop ends when items list has only "a" and "b" ?

Comment: Here you will find the answer https://www.quora.com/Why-can%E2%80%99t-you-modify-lists-through-for-in-loops-in-Python